# How can I get P4 last changelist number in Ant target

Tags: ant, perforce

I want to create a ant target that can open a new p4 changelist and integrate 2 branches.
I can do most of the job using p4 tasks
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/perforce.html

However, one thing I don't know how to do is that I want to put the last changelist number in the description, but I don't know how to get the last changelist number in Ant.

Does anyone know how to do that? Please give me some suggestion.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out P4Ant - it has tasks for looking up changes in a certain path.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4ant/p4tasks.html